# IntelliJ OSGi dependency resolution

Tags: intellij-idea, osgi

I've been searching for quite a while now, no result:

Working on an OSGi project with IntelliJ, how can I make IntelliJ resolve dependencies, as specified in `MANIFEST.MF`, to other bundles in the same project other than from the specified OSGi framework (a.k.a. "target platform")?

**Edit:**

Let's say I have a bundle `com.example.projecta` with the following manifest:

```
...
Require-Bundle: com.example.projectb;bundle-version="1.0.0"
...
```

and my modules look like this:

- `com.example.projecta`
- `com.example.projectb` (1.0.0)

How do I make IntelliJ resolve the dependency to `com.example.projectb` by reading the manifest, *not* by adding the depedency manually?

Comment: How is your project structured? What tools are you using? For example, when working with Maven, you'd have to add those bundles as dependencies in the `provided` scope to your `pom.xml`

Comment: I updated question to be more specific. The affected projects aren't Maven project, but if that's required to solve the problem I could mavenize them. Generally the team works with Eclipse which resolves the dependency out of the box; however I'd like to stick to IntelliJ else I'm going nuts.

Comment: Have you tried following these steps https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/osgi.html ?

Comment: There are no "steps", but yes I read the documentation and configured as much as I could, but still don't see how I can make it resolve dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA cannot do that, unfortunately. That would require some kind of repository (like Maven, but for bundles).

Comment: Bundles are just JARs with manifests. _Maven for OSGi bundles_ is Maven.